# cPanel filing up server with core dumps due to tailwatchd failures due to out of memory?

Tags: memory, hard-drive

Recently the disk usage on one of my machines has been climbing steadily.  Upon investigating, I found that the

```
/usr/local/cpanel/install
```

directory was full of core fump files from cPanel.  about 106GB worth!
 all the files seemed to be due to 'tailwatchd'

```
> [/usr/local/cpanel/install]# file core.9049
core.9049: ELF 64-bit LSB core file AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),
SVR4-style, from 'tailwatchd'
```

so i looked at the log files for tailwatchd and found they were due tomemory issues...

```
> [/usr/local/cpanel/install]# tail -n 10
/usr/local/cpanel/logs/tailwatchd_log
Out of memory!
Out of memory!
Out of memory!
Callback called exit, <GEN15> line 35842.
END failed--call queue aborted at /usr/local/cpanel/bin/tailwatchd
line 9, <GEN15> line 35842.
```

thus it seems like a memory issue... it's strange because this only started happening out of the blue a day ago.  i did install Munin about two weeks ago, but thats the only major change on the box i'm aware of.  could that be a culprit?  munin shows the constant increase in commited memory from day one of being installed... but the disk usage only started growing a day ago.

keep in mind i'm a programmer that has been forced to wear the system admin hat the last week or so.  let me know if more details would help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem solved.  apparently cpanel was spawning hundreds of those tailwatchd processes.  it happened after cpanel's automatic updates was accidentally turned on.  killed these processes and got rid of the 106GB of dump files.  all is well.

word for the wise, make certain cpanel is on manual rather than automatic updates.